# unity mvp Matrix on ios

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, cg

I am working on water simulation, I need to sample _CameraDepthTexture to get Opaque depth, it works well on Windows. But the shader get different depth on IOS.

```
vert:
o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);           
o.ref = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);
COMPUTE_EYEDEPTH(o.ref.z);
frag:
uniform sampler2D_float _CameraDepthTexture;
float raw_depth = UNITY_SAMPLE_DEPTH(tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, UNITY_PROJ_COORD(uv2)));
```

On windows, the raw_depth is around 0.98, but On IOS, The raw_depth is around 0.51.
I guess this result interrelate with MVP in difference Platform.

Comment: Hmm... try `o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex)`. If will be `undeclared identifier UnityObjectToClipPos` , use `#include "UnityCG.cginc" ` or download new unity version. Actually i never seem like this situation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  but it doesn't work,I have searched for the solution, I have find these  formulas `GL: zn=zc/wc=(fz+nz+2nf)/((f-n)z);
DX/Metal: zn=zc/wc=(fz+nf)/((f-n)z);`does it interrelate with this question?

Comment: I don't know .  on windows and on iOS `DX/Metal` same formula. I found some thing about matrix, maybe it will be helpful [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1359718/what-do-the-values-in-the-matrix4x4-for-cameraproj.html?childToView=1359877#answer-1359877)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I find the problem. it doesn't interrelate with MVP, mac or ios optimize the render step, if there is no light or image effect, it close the updateCameraDepthTexture, so the value in CameraDepthTexture is default value, in script, we should add ` Camera cam = Camera.current;
   cam.depthTextureMode = DepthTextureMode.Depth;`.